# How does 'even though' relate to in logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

> Lets say I have something like this:
>
> Define the propositional variable:
>
> • b : Joe has maintained a B average.
>
> • c : Joe has received below a C in a class.
>
> • h : Joe is eligible for the honors program.
>
> Translate the following sentence into logical propositions.  For
>   example the statement:  ”If Joe has maintained an B average, then he
>   is eligible for the honors program” would be translated as b → h .
>
> Joe has maintained a B average even though he did receive a grade
>   below a C in a class.

How does the 'even though' translate into logic? I think that it would be and $∧$ and so the expression would be:

$$b\space∧\space c$$

but I am not certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right - $\wedge$ is the correct interpretation. English statements such as "even though", "however", "but", and "yet" all have usages that contrast facts, but they are all translated to "and" in propositional logic.

Comment: Exactly, their use is retorical. Logically, they are just conjunctions

Comment: What would be some "English" words that equate to "OR" in logic? Or is this a thing we only have for "AND" ?